# Different in permissions for SSAS

Tags: ssas

What is the different between "Full control" and "Process database"?

[image]

Comment: one means you can process the other means you can do everything.

Comment: You are telling me that the user can only process the cube as a process database?

Answer (score 0):

Full control includes changing the structure, like adding or removing dimensions, attributes, or measures - and of course includes processing.